# How to access the frame outside the function in python

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

How can I access the scroll_frame outside the function so that the new_frame will be inside the scroll_frame in the code below.

```
def scroll():
    container = LabelFrame(root)

    my_canvas = Canvas(container)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    scroll_y = Scrollbar(container, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox('all')))

    scroll_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scroll_frame, anchor=NW)

    container.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


new_frame = Frame(scroll_frame)

for i in range(25):
    Button(new_frame, text='click'+str(i)).pack()

scroll()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you need to put those code inside `scroll()`?

Comment: If scroll_frame is the parent of new_frame, then it must be created before new_frame.

Comment: @acw1668, because I want scrollbar for many frames and I don't want to use same code again and again. That's why I made a scroll function so that I put each newly created frame in scroll frame

Comment: @8349697, Yes I am aware of that.
But I want to make scroll function only once and will use it whenever necessary. So please tell me the way how this function is going to work.

Comment: Try to return the created scroll_frame object from the function.

Comment: Call the function once at the beginning (`scroll_frame = scroll()`) and pack your new frames there.

Comment: Then it is better to use class instead of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `scroll_frame`, you should return it from `scroll()`.

Suggest to return `container` as well and don't call `container.pack(...)` inside `scroll()` because it is more flexible.

Also suggest to pass the parent to `scroll()` as well instead of hard-coded `root` inside it.

```py
from tkinter import *

def scroll(parent):
    container = LabelFrame(parent)

    my_canvas = Canvas(container, highlightthickness=0)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    scroll_y = Scrollbar(container, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

    scroll_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scroll_frame, anchor=NW)

    # bind <Configure> on scroll_frame instead of my_canvas
    scroll_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox('all')))

    return container, scroll_frame

root = Tk()

container, scroll_frame = scroll(root)
container.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Is new_frame necessary? Why not use scroll_frame directly?
new_frame = Frame(scroll_frame)
new_frame.pack()

for i in range(25):
    Button(new_frame, text='click'+str(i)).pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

*Note that if you want to use `scroll()` repeatedly, better use class instead of function.*

---

Update: using class implemenatation:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class ScrollableFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        vscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)

        self.scroll_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
        self.scroll_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
        canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.scroll_frame, anchor="nw")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    container = ScrollableFrame(root)
    container.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    for i in range(25):
        tk.Button(container.scroll_frame, text=f"click {i}").pack(fill="x")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time @acw1668.
And about the new_frame I am not sure about it, I need to check whether it is possible in my code or not.
I am very new to OOP, I started using OOP only for a week now. Can you please show me how to do it.

Comment: And again I don't understand why you suggest to pass the parent to scroll() instead of hard-coded root inside it.
And can  you explain what you did in this line, container, scroll_frame = scroll(root).

Comment: If you want to used this *scroll* feature in another window later, hard-coded `root` cannot achieve it.  For second question, since `scroll()` returns two objects (a tuple of two frames actually) now, `container, scroll_frame = scroll(root)` will unpack the returned tuple by `scroll()` into `container` and `scroll_frame`.

Comment: hey thanks for the explanation.
And can you please tell me how this code can be integrated in OOP method?

Comment: Answer updated with class implementation.

Comment: Thanks,
But why my canvas is in the root and not in the frame I want?

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @acw1668 is good one but I was unable to make the scrollbar in the frame I want.

So finally I came with this:

```
from tkinter import * # you should avoid wildcard import

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
t1 = Text(root)

f2 = Frame(root)
t2 = Text(root)

def scroll(in_frame, lbl, txt):
    in_frame_lbl = Label(in_frame, text=lbl)
    in_frame_lbl.pack(fill=X)
    in_frame.pack(fill=X)

    scroll_y = Scrollbar(in_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N, fill=Y)

    txt.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
    txt.pack(fill=X)
    scroll_y.config(command=txt.yview)
    txt.config(state='disabled')

scroll(f1, 'Scroll in Frame 1', t1)
scroll(f2, 'Scroll in Frame 2', t2)

for i in range(5):
    Button(f1, text='click'+str(i)).pack(fill=X)
    Entry(f2).pack()

root.mainloop()
```